# Given distance covered as a function of time, find acceleration.

Tags: derivatives

[image]

Since this question covers more aspects of differentiation and mathematical manipulation than kinematics, I am posting it here.

My attempt : On differentiating position(x) once, we get velocity(v) and on differentiating position twice, we get acceleration(A).

Therefore, $xv=at+b$ and $A x^1/3= (vx) (x-vx) $ are the two equations I got. But, I can't seem to express acceleration completely in terms of position, as given in the options below.

Are the options wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: I have $v^2+Ax=a$ so that $A={a-v^2 \over x}$ does it agree with your expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a,b,c$ constant:
$$x=\sqrt{at^2+2bt+c}$$
$$v={at+b\over \sqrt{at^2+2bt+c}}$$
$$A={a\sqrt{at^2+2bt+c} -{(at+b)^2\over \sqrt{at^2+2bt+c}} \over at^2+2bt+c}$$
$$A={a(at^2+2bt+c)-(at+b) ^2\over(\sqrt{at^2+2bt+c} )^3 }$$
$$A={ac-b ^2\over(\sqrt{at^2+2bt+c} )^3 }= {ac-b ^2\over x^3 }$$

Comment: It doesn't match any option

Comment: It matches (A)... as $a,b,c$ are constants.